# Emerald Night Piston replacement + jamming issue

Tags: trains, set-modification

I'm just wondering if I can get replacement piston rods for my Emerald Night, since the rods are easily the least impressive part of the model. I'm wondering if there is a form of kit that can make the rods look more like one of a real train? (Shown Below)

[image: Real Train Piston Rods]

Also, anyone have a fix for the jamming issue? I think I have a temporary fix but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you mean by "the jamming issue"?

Answer (score 5):

There is a [Bricklink store](https://www.bricklink.com/store.asp?p=zephyr) that sells custom-made train driver rods. I've never bought any so I can't speak to the quality. There are supposedly limitless varieties possible but given that you're looking for one that matches a set you should be able to find some already-made for that set.

[image]

Regarding the jamming issue, the most common problem is when the wheels aren't properly quartered. When building, the pin holes for the pistons on one side should be at 12:00 (top) and on the other side at 3:00 (front). This helps prevent jamming.

Answer (score 3):

I found [building instructions for a BR 23-001-L](http://railbricks.com/instructions/br-23-001-l/) that has a more realistic look on the pistons.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2n8uh-DBLFg

[image: BR 23-001-L]

[Here is a pdf tutorial](http://www.brickshelf.com/gallery/Ben/presentations/BrickfestPDX2007/brickfest07_steam_engines.pdf) on what to think about when modelling steam engines in LEGO. There are pictures of different examples that has various solutions for pistons.